# Копирование из html кода определенных слов в документ

Tags: python, html, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день! Подскажите, есть кусок html кода, как можно на pythone реализовать поиск определенных символов или слов и копировать слова или цифры **после** или **до** них в документ. 
Например:
:

```
>   <tr style="border-top: solid 1px;">
>             <td><strong>Дата 01.05.2014</strong></td>
>           <td><strong>Турпакет, Турция, Алания, 4 дня</strong></td>
>           <td style="width: 120px;"><strong>15 393 руб. <br /> (~
> 343 € , ~ 467

                $)</strong></td>
```

Надо выцепить "01.05.2014",эти цифры всегда идут после слова *"дата"*, которое никогда не меняется в отличие от них самих, так же надо дальше найти слова после неизменяемого слова *"Турпакет"* (в данном случае это "Турция, Алания") но проблема в том что в отличие от даты "01.05.2014" в которой количество символов всегда одно, тут может быть больше или меньше, но точно известно, что **после** них  **всегда** идут цифры (или слово "дня\дней" или тег `</strong>` – любое, что может быть использовано как якорь для определения конца)

Мне бы хотя бы примерный алгоритм, а я его как нибудь допилю уже, просто я вообще не программист, но если есть от чего отталкиваться, я уж как нить разберусь.

p.s. То что копируется из html кода это как вариант, возможно проще будет из xml, просто я не знаком с тонкостями.

Answer (score 2):

для парсинга можно использовать например [lxml](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html). 
Сначала искать нужную ноду, а затем парсить её по подходящему алгоритму

```
text = page.cssselect("#node_id").text_content()
data = parse(text)
```

А ноду парсить с помощью регулярных выражений

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, будет проще работать напрямую с DOM?

[Grab — python библиотека для парсинга сайтов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127584/)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте не выяснять подробности и тонкости (если не собираетесь стать программистом), "погулите" на тему регулярных выражений `regexp`, изучите синтаксис и основы основ, наверняка должна быть статья и на хабре.

После этого вы запросто напишете свой небольшой парсер, а знание регулярных выражений  лишним не станет, вам они могут пригодится и для правок в больших текстах (например при использовании sublime) и...

... при желании стать программистом ;)

Comment: Вариант:
    
    import re
    
    text = """
    >   <tr style="border-top: solid 1px;">
    >             <td><strong>Дата 01.05.2014</strong></td>
    >           <td><strong>Турпакет, Турция, Алания, 4 дня</strong></td>
    >           <td style="width: 120px;"><strong>15 393 руб. <br /> (~
    > 343 € , ~ 467
    
                    $)</strong></td>
                    """

    pack = re.compile(r"Турпакет, (.*?)<")
    date = re.compile(r"Дата (.*?)<")

    print pack.findall(text)[0] # список
    print date.findall(text)[0] # список

Comment: Какие именно стоят перед вами задачи? Возможно вам вообще лучше подойдет что-нибудь типа:

    import nltk

    # text = "" # ваш кусок html
    print nltk.clean_html(text)
    > 
    >    Дата 01.05.2014 
    >    Турпакет, Турция, Алания, 4 дня 
    >    15 393 руб. (~
    > 343 € , ~ 467
    
        $)